# aws glue pyspark remove struct in an array but keep the data and save into dynamodb

Tags: pyspark, amazon-dynamodb, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

A dynamodb table is exported to s3 and aws glue crawler crawls the s3 data.
Aws glue jobs take the source from the crawled data and here's the schema that was transformed by MergeLineItems:

```
def MergeLineItems(rec):
    rec["lineItems1"] = {}
    a = []
    for x in rec["lineItems"]:
        a.append(x["M"])
    rec["lineItems1"] = a
    return rec
  
mapped_dyF =  Map.apply(frame = Transform0, f = MergeLineItems)
```

The schema is like this:

```
    -- lineItems1: array
    |    |-- element: struct
    |    |    |-- price: struct
    |    |    |    |-- N: string
    |    |    |-- grade: struct
    |    |    |    |-- S: string
    |    |    |-- expectedAmount: struct
    |    |    |    |-- N: string
    |    |    |-- notifiedAmount: struct
    |    |    |    |-- N: string
```

When I run the aws glue job and the data that was saved into a dynamodb is like this:

```
[
    {
        "M":
        {
            "expectedAmount":
            {
                "M":
                {
                    "N":
                    {
                        "S": "10"
                    }
                }
            },
            "grade":
            {
                "M":
                {
                    "S":
                    {
                        "S": "GradeAAA"
                    }
                }
            },
            "notifiedAmount":
            {
                "M":
                {
                    "N":
                    {
                        "S": "0"
                    }
                }
            },
            "price":
            {
                "M":
                {
                    "N":
                    {
                        "S": "2.15"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
]
```

While the data from the original dynamodb is different than this. How can I change the data into this one:

```
[
    {
        "M":
        {
            "expectedAmount":
            {
                "N": "10"
            },
            "notifiedAmount":
            {
                "N": "0"
            },
            "grade":
            {
                "S": "GradeAAA"
            },
            "price":
            {
                "N": "2.15"
            }
        }
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working. Here's my answer:

```
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database = "mydb", table_name = "data", transformation_ctx = "DataSource0")

Transform0 = ApplyMapping.apply(frame = DataSource0, mappings = [("item.lineItems.L", "array", "lineItems", "array")], transformation_ctx = "Transform0")


def MergeLineItems(rec):
    rec["lineItems1"] = {}
    a = []
    for x in rec["lineItems"]:
        val = x["M"]["expectedAmount"]["N"]
        x["M"]["expectedAmount"] = Decimal(val)
        
        val = x["M"]["notifiedAmount"]["N"]
        x["M"]["notifiedAmount"] = Decimal(val)
        
        val = x["M"]["grade"]["S"]
        x["M"]["grade"] = str(val)
        
        val = x["M"]["price"]["N"]
        x["M"]["price"] = Decimal(val)
        
        a.append(x["M"])
    rec["lineItems1"] = a
    return rec
  
mapped_dyF =  Map.apply(frame = Transform0, f = MergeLineItems)
mapped_dyF = DropFields.apply(mapped_dyF, paths=['lineItems'])
mapped_dyF = RenameField.apply(mapped_dyF, "lineItems1", "lineItems") 


glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=mapped_dyF,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.region": "us-east-1",
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "mydb",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)
job.commit()
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Minah for posting this question and answer, I was looking exactly for this (mapping DynamoDB arrays exported to S3 from an AWS Glue Python ETL job) and this was the only helpful post I could find.

This version worked for me, removing the additional steps of DropField and RenameField and creating new items instead of overwriting them:

```py
DataSource = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(database="mydb", table_name="data",
Transform = ApplyMapping.apply(frame=DataSource0, mappings=[("item.lineItems.L", "array", "lineItems", "array")],
                               transformation_ctx="Transform")


def MergeLineItems(record):
    mappedLineItems = []
    for lineItem in record["lineItems"]:
        mappedLineItems.append({
            "expectedAmount": Decimal(lineItem["M"]["expectedAmount"]["N"]),
            "notifiedAmount": Decimal(lineItem["M"]["notifiedAmount"]["N"]),
            "grade": lineItem["M"]["grade"]["S"],
            "price": Decimal(lineItem["M"]["price"]["N"]),
        })
    record["lineItems"] = mappedLineItems
    return record


Mapped = Map.apply(frame=Transform0, f=MergeLineItems, transformation_ctx="Mapped")

glueContext.write_dynamic_frame_from_options(
    frame=Mapped,
    connection_type="dynamodb",
    connection_options={
        "dynamodb.region": "us-east-1",
        "dynamodb.output.tableName": "mydb",
        "dynamodb.throughput.write.percent": "1.0"
    }
)
job.commit()
```